# Checar se o autoplay foi permido

Tags: html5-video

Estou trabalhando em um site que na home, tem um vídeo de background e um carrossel de texto por cima. Gostaria de, ao invés de tentar enganar o navegador e forçar o `autoplay`, que carregasse uma imagem de fundo. Já tentei colocar um `<p>` dentro do `<vídeo>` pra testar, mas não dá certo, acho que porque o navegador entende que source tá ali, só não foi ativada.

Comment: Está a procura do atributo [`poster`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_poster) da etiqueta `<video>` ? Que força uma imagem de fundo até que o video comece?